# How can I make hyphens work with spell-check in PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, hyphenation

I sometimes manually introduce a hyphen in a long word to split it across two lines. I do this when I justify a paragraph to keep the automatic spacing between words small.

Example without hyphen:
[image]

Example with hyphen:
[image]

In the last example the spacing of the first line is much smaller than in the first example and looks better.

However, the word that was hyphenated now is marked by the spell checker as a mistake.

So, my question: is there a way to introduce a hyphen that doesn't trigger the spell-checker to mark it as a mistake and still recognize it as a valid word?

I understand there is no automatic hyphenation available in PowerPoint 365, so I need to resort to manual hyphenation in these cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I do not think this is possible.**

You are intentionally misspelling a word by inserting a manual hyphen. I understand it's logical and I'm not arguing the reasoning. I get it. But there's no way, that I'm aware of, to tell PowerPoint that some specific character should be overlooked or skipped during spellcheck.

It would be no different than manually inserting a `q` in a word, of course it's going to be seen as misspelled, even if the insertion is intentional.

And.. what if you *unintentionally* inserted a hyphen when one wasn't needed? You probably don't want PowerPoint to ignore such instances.

PowerPoint, as a whole, is *not* a text editor. Which is why it doesn't have hyphenation options. Traditionally, the slide design should be adjusted to *not* use force justification if it becomes problematic, or things like this just have to be tolerated/accommodated due to the lack of text features in PowerPoint.